# Image from Gallery in Android 6(Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-6.0-marshmallow

In My Application I am trying to Pick image from galley, so as to pass that image to server.

Code is working fine on Android 5 and below, but for Android 6 on Nexus 5 I am not able to get image information. ***Log trace which I got***

**Note**: Code is working fine on Android 5 and below versions

```
11-06 12:27:43.736: W/System.err(31678): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A//media/external/images/media/19138/ACTUAL/94710853 from pid=31678, uid=10111 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
11-06 12:27:43.757: W/System.err(31678): 
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.ContentFilesystem.openCursorForURL(ContentFilesystem.java:258)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.ContentFilesystem.getFileMetadataForLocalURL(ContentFilesystem.java:169)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFileMetadata(FileUtils.java:822)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$500(FileUtils.java:52)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$15.run(FileUtils.java:394)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:551)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-06 12:27:43.758: W/System.err(31678): 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: nice explanation http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: I guess you should try to decode the image in the same context without passing the uri to another context and decode image there(like startActivity).

Answer (score 22):

DO it this way...
on Button Click check for SDK Version, using the following code that I copied from http://web.archive.org/web/20160111030837/http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html —

> ```
>  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
>     // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
>                         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
>                                 Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
>                                 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>     
>                             // Should we show an explanation?
>                             if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
>                                     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
>     
>                                 // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>                                 // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>                                 // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>     
>                             } else {
>     
>                                 // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>     
>                                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                                         new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
>                                         MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
>     
>                                 // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
>                                 // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
>                                 // result of the request.
>                             }
>                         }else{
>                             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
>                                     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
>                         }
>                     }else {
>     
>                         Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
>                         photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
>                         startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
>                     }
> ```

after that in Override method onRequestPermissionsResult write this code:

> ```
>  case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
>                 // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>                 if (grantResults.length > 0
>                         && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                     // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                     // contacts-related task you need to do.
>                     Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
>                     photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
>                     startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
>                 } else {
>
>                     // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                     // functionality that depends on this permission.
>                 }
>                 return;
>             }
> ```

After that

> ```
> @Override
>     protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>         super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
>
>         switch (reqCode) {  case SELECT_PHOTO:
>                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>                     try {
>                         final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
>                         final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
>                         final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
>                         contactimage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
>                     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>
>                 }
> ```

Comment: What is  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and where I initialize it??

Comment: it is a static int value asign it any int value but that value should not be used for any other request. for example if for camera you are using value 1 then for this you can use any integer value except 1..

Answer (score 5):

I believe you'll need to request the permissions to the user at runtime (this is one of the most noticeable changes from api 22 to 23).

You can try this snippet, extracted from the [Android Developers permission page](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){    
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
  }
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get image from Gallery in Marshmallow, You are required to grant **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission at run time. Android Version M has changed the way permissions are granted to applications.

Before Marshmallow, all required permissions are granted at once and that is at the time of installation. But in Marshmallow, User is asked for permission at the time only if that permission is required, and the User has to either Allow or Deny that permission.

Below two links will help you more. Link 1 is from official documentation of Android, and Link 2 is a blog which has explained this issue with a working example.

Link1: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Link2: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The image showed in Imageview after picking the image from gallery using

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, videoIdentifier);
```

and decoding the bitmap image from the URI

But saving the URI for future use and reopening the app and reusing the saved URI not worked. Couldn't decoding the bitmap from URI.

I solved the issue by extracting the original content uri from URI path

```
public String RemoveUnwantedString(String pathUri){
    //pathUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/5213/ORIGINAL/NONE/2106970034"
    String[] d1 = pathUri.split("content://");
    for (String item1:d1) {
        if (item1.contains("media/")) {
            String[] d2 = item1.split("/ORIGINAL/");
            for (String item2:d2) {
                if (item2.contains("media/")) {
                    pathUri = "content://" + item2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //pathUri = "content://media/external/video/media/5213"
    return pathUri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

This is the simple method that i have created with other examples

1. call CHECKGALLERYPERMISSION() method where you want and paste the code inside method

   ```
    private void CHECKGALLERYPERMISSION()
    {
       int MY_READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =1 ;
       int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setType("image/*");
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
       }
       else
       {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
           {
               requestPermissions(
                       new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                       MY_READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
           }
           else
           {
           }
       }
     }
     @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
     permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      if (requestCode == MY_READ_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
           && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
      {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setType("image/*");
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
   }
      }
     @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
   {
       Uri uri = data.getData();
       try
       {
           Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(YourActivity.this.getContentResolver(), uri);
           imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
     }
   ```

## Note

1. in fragement use getactivity() instead of activity.this
2. if android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working change this to Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in all places