# How to get image from gallery in android marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Hi i am working in app were user can select image when he is registering an account. I am able to get image on lollipop but when i am testing it in marshmallow then i am not getting file and its name, I am able to ask permission from user and when i am selecting image from gallery i am not getting any file or its name

This is my Code

```
        select_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23) {
                    if (checkPermission()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("*/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

                    }else{
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

                }
            }

        });

My Permissions

private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Register.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


private void requestPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Register.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to access images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Register.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setType("*/*");
                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);





                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
        }

    }
```

After Selecting Image

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            if (null != filePath) {
                try {

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    // img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    if (filePath.getScheme().equals("content")) {
                        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(filePath, null, null, null, null)) {
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                file_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                Toast.makeText(this, file_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                img_name.setText(file_name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting why its not working in marshmallow even i have given permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image from Gallery in Android 6(Marshmallow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617947/image-from-gallery-in-android-6marshmallow)

Comment: I have just checked i am getting image but i am not getting name in marshmallow, can you please help what should i do to get name

Comment: `if (filePath.getScheme().equals("content"))`. Please put filePath in your textview or toast it to see that the filename is at the end.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not pick files from Gallery app to begin with. But uses an inbuild Android file chooser.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

                filePath = data.getData();
                if (null != filePath) {
                    try {

                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                        // img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        if (filePath.getScheme().equals("content")) {
                            try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(filePath, null, null, null, null)) {
                                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    file_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                    Toast.makeText(this, file_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    img_name.setText(file_name);
                                }
                            }
                        }else {

                            String path= data.getData().getPath();
                            file_name=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                            img_name.setText(file_name);
                            Toast.makeText(this, file_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i was selecting file , then i was  not going to this condition

```
 if (filePath.getScheme().equals("content"))
```

so in else condition i have given this

```
 String path= data.getData().getPath();
                            file_name=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                            img_name.setText(file_name);
                            Toast.makeText(this, file_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

***To get image from gallery on any api level then follow this :***

*Copy and paste all 4 function to your activity
And call this to open gallery **galleryPermissionDialog();***

Variable used

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_MANUAL = 5;
```

Permission need to add for lower than marshmallow

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Function 1:**

```
void openGallry() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    }
```

**Function 2 :**

```
void galleryPermissionDialog() {

    int hasWriteContactsPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityProfile.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityProfile.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;

    } else {
        openGallry();
    }
}
```

**Function 3 :**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            // Check for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

            boolean showRationale = false;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All Permissions Granted
                    galleryPermissionDialog();
                } else {
                    showRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    if (showRationale) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("Read Storage Permission required for this app ",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        galleryPermissionDialog();

                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        showMessageOKCancel("Read Storage Permission required for this app ",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        Toast.makeText(ActivityProfile.this, "Please Enable the Read Storage permission in permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                        intent.setData(uri);
                                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MANUAL);
                                    }
                                });

                        //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                    }


                }


            } else {
                galleryPermissionDialog();

            }

        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

**Function 4 :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                   /* final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    img_profile.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);*/
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    pictureFile = saveBitmapToFile(new File(picturePath));
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(new File(picturePath)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imgProfile);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Function 5 :**

```
public void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityProfile.this)
            .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

file/* is not a valid MIME type. You should use */* if you want to support any type of file. The files you see are unselectable because they are not of the correct MIME type.

With the introduction of virtual files in Android 7.0 (files that don't have a bytestream and therefore cannot be directly uploaded), you should most definitely add CATEGORY_OPENABLE to your Intent:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#virtual_files

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_OPENABLE

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("*/*");
    // Only get openable files
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Choose File to Upload.."), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}


public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

String filename =getFileName(yourfileuri);

Comment: I have just checked i am getting image but i am not getting name in marshmallow, can you please help what should i do to get name

Comment: reffer this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html